# Section header not displaying correctly in ASP.NET Core view

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-5

I am migrating an application from ASP.NET MVC 5 running on .NET 4.8 to ASP.NET Core 6 MVC.

The MVC 5 application has the following in an Index.cshtml file:

```
@section header
{
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/_ModeHeader.cshtml", Model.Mode, new ViewDataDictionary { { "text", "Salaries" }, { "icon", "fa-money-check" } })
}
```

I updated it to the following in the new application:

```
@section header {
    @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/_ModeHeader.cshtml", Model.Mode, new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { { "text", "Salaries" }, { "icon", "fa-money-check" } })
}
```

_ModeHeader.cshtml:

```
@using Project.Extensions.MVC
@using Project.Models

@model Enums.Mode

@{
    if (!ViewData.ContainsKey("icon"))
    {
        ViewData["icon"] = "fa-list-alt";
    }
}

<div class="border-bottom row">
    <div class="col">
        <span class="h1">
            @switch (Model)
            {
                case Enums.Mode.None:
                    break;
                case Enums.Mode.Browse:
                    @IconExtensions.BuildColoredIconTag(ViewData["icon"].ToString(), "text-info")
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
            @ViewData["text"]
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The expected result is an icon, a space, and the text Salaries.

The current result is the text Normal, a space, and the text Salaries.

**UPDATE**:

The text "Normal" is the result of updating the line `var finalHtml = icon.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);` from the old application to `var finalHtml = icon.TagRenderMode.ToString();`. Since `TagRenderMode` is "Normal" by default, that is where the value comes from.

IconExtensions.cs:

```
public static class IconExtensions
{
    public static HtmlString BuildIconTag(string iconName)
    {
        var icon = BuildInternalIconTag(iconName);

        var htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        htmlBuilder.Append(icon);

        var finalHtml = icon.TagRenderMode.ToString();

        return new HtmlString(finalHtml);
    }

    public static HtmlString BuildColoredIconTag(string iconName, string color)
    {
        var icon = BuildInternalColoredIconTag(iconName, color);

        var htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        htmlBuilder.Append(icon);

        var finalHtml = icon.TagRenderMode.ToString();

        return new HtmlString(finalHtml);
    }

    public static TagBuilder BuildInternalIconTag(string iconName)
    {
        var icon = new TagBuilder("i");

        icon.AddCssClass("fas");
        icon.AddCssClass("fa-fw");
        icon.AddCssClass(iconName);
        icon.MergeAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");

        return icon;
    }

    public static TagBuilder BuildInternalColoredIconTag(string iconName, string color)
    {
        var icon = new TagBuilder("i");

        icon.AddCssClass("fas");
        icon.AddCssClass("fa-fw");
        icon.AddCssClass(iconName);
        icon.AddCssClass(color);
        icon.MergeAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");

        return icon;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you include the code for _ModeHeader.cshtml as well here? Did you try this without switching to PartialAsync?

Comment: Added code for _ModeHeader.cshtml. I receive a warning to use <partial> if I don't use PartiaAsync.

Comment: Thanks for the additional code. Warnings are informational and shouldn't stop your code from executing. Did it work as expected other than giving a warning?

Comment: it runs, but it displays the same incorrect "Normal Salaries" instead of an icon, space, Salaries.

Comment: I just realized where "Normal" comes from => In the old IconExtensions.cs file, I have `var finalHtml = icon.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);` and I updated it to `var finalHtml = icon.TagRenderMode.ToString();`. Since `TagRenderMode` is Normal by default, that is where that value is coming from.

Comment: Good deal. It's helpful to reduce the number of changes at one time. Is IconExtensions from a package or is that your code? Ah, sounds like the problem is in that BuildColoredIconTag method then.

Comment: It is code developed internally.

Comment: We need to see that code, too, then. :D

Comment: I added the IconExtensions.cs code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is just setting `finalHtml` to "Normal"

```
var finalHtml = icon.TagRenderMode.ToString();
```

This line is using just "Normal" to make the `HtmlString`

```
return new HtmlString(finalHtml);
```

You are not using your `icon` object at all at this point.

You probably want something more like:

```
public static HtmlString BuildColoredIconTag(string iconName, string color)
{
    var icon = BuildInternalColoredIconTag(iconName, color);
    var writer = new StringWriter();
    icon.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);

    return new HtmlString(writer.ToString());
}
```

Comment: The line `var writer = new TextWriter();` produces error CS0144.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been StringWriter, I believe.